# Why do datasheets include Tape and Reel information?

Tags: pcb-design, datasheet, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, footprint

Specifically:
 - Does a PCB designer need to be concerned with tape and reel information? 
 - Is the information intended for PCB assemblers, pick and place machines, etc? 
**- Will a pick and place machine mess up if you create your part with an orientation different from the way the part is oriented on the reel?**

Answer (score 5):

You might be concerned with the quantity per reel (for costing), and with other details to make sure that your assembly shop(s) can actually handle the parts.

For example, some OSRAM LEDs are double density on the tape and older machines cannot handle them.

If you know more about the part orientation in the tape and the center point definition it should be possible to make library footprints that require less labour to set up pick&place, but I don't think most designers do that.

Edit: Re orientation- PCB assemblers do a lot of 'touching' of the P&P file and such problems will be ironed out manually provided they get unambiguous direction on the proper orientation on the PCB. If you did the pick and place in-house you might have reason to make it better, but when you're getting charged for setup so I don't think it matters that much. It's not like bare PCBs where the Gerber files are generally plotted with basically no alteration. Read a bit more about the real situation [here](http://www.frontdoor.biz/HowToPCB/HowToPCB-extra/ResolvingComponentPolarityProblems.pdf)

For example, one assembler I use for small-quantity high-end work creates a separate sheet for each component in the design.

Comment: Reel prices are a factor that you should keep in mind when selecting parts and designing a board. This aspect should almost have it's own answer [with upvotes ;)].

Answer (score 4):

I don't think board designers need the tape and reel information, but assembly shops do, for loading and programming their pick-and-place machines.

Comment: I added another bullet point to my question. If a part is created with a different pin 1 orientation than the tape, and the CAD software generates a file that instructs the part to be rotated, this must introduce some potential for error. I assume some assembly houses double check this against your silkscreen, but not all. In this case, board designers do need to be designing with the tape and reel information in mind?